# How to line break in a table-cell component?

Tags: html, css

I've allready seen question about it but no proper answer so I'm asking it again, what is your solution to line break a content in a table-cell?

I want every cell of my table to have the same border spacing (left/right) so if a text content is wilder than the majority of the cell, it just go to the line.

[image: Text wilder than image]

As you can see the New Orleans is wilder than the image and this is messing with the border spacing.

I tough of something like `max-width:100%` on the text but it appears to have no effect.

Here is a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/r2bp3gfe/2/) if you want to play with it a bit.

Just so you have an idea, the code is pretty basic :

```
    <div display:table; border-spacing:10px;>
       <span display:table-row;>
          <div display:table-cell;> Content </div>
          <div display:table-cell;> Content </div>
          <div display:table-cell;> Content </div>
          ...
       </span><!-- Every 5 elements -->
       <span display:table-row;>
          <div display:table-cell;> Content </div>  x5
          ...
       </span>
       ...
    </div>
```

Comment: An LI element can only be a child of a UL or OL element. Please fix this. :)

Comment: @Kyle Ho I forgot to put it in the Fiddle but they are ;), Its edited

Comment: Add `max-width: 85px;` in `.append li` class of css. like  `.append li {
    max-width: 85px; }`

Comment: first fix you **DOM** as li can only be child of `<ol>` OR `<ul>`, and add this *CSS* for your `<a>` `{word-break: break-all;
max-width: 85px;
white-space: normal;
display: block;}`

Comment: No, they're not. There are no <ul> in your fiddle. You cannot set `max-width: 100%;` on a child to an element width no fixed width. Either set a fixed width on your <li>'s or set a max-width on your <span>'s with your text.

Comment: No, your edit does not fix your broken DOM. <li> must be a direct child of <ul> or <ol>. <ul> or >ol> can't have anything but <li> as a child.

Comment: See your jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/frayne_konok/r2bp3gfe/3/

Answer (score 2):

First of all your HTML is invalid. `li` must be child of `ul` or `ol`.

Now since all images are same width (85px) you can specify that li (single block element) is same width as image. `li {width: 85px;}`. Then your text will not expand parent element.

---

For responsive design:

1. Make sure your images are responsive - `<img class="imgLittle" src="{{URL}}">` / `.imgLittle {width: 100%; /* height must be auto */}`
2. Apply grid system for your blocks.

Comment: This is an effective solution for my specific problem but let say I want it to be responsiv ?

Comment: hum the problem is that images are displayed as background of div, I cant let the div without proportion but the answer is great anyway; I up vote you :)

Comment: @Baldráni Just move it to image tag.

Comment: Hum realy not sure this is even possible : https://jsfiddle.net/Baldrani/r2bp3gfe/5/

Comment: @Baldráni Please read some Html tutorials. Instead of putting URL to `style` attribute, put it in `src`: `<img src="http://data4.voyagesarabais.com/i/photos/custom/900/500/5/159431.jpg"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Try your jsFiddle...
I update it just adding a new div with a class called: text for your text.

And also i change your image width to 100%.

HTML:

```
<ul>
<div class="append">
   <span>
      <li>
         <a href="/voyage/ameriques/etats-unis/boston/">
            <div class="imgLittle" style="background-image:url(http://data4.voyagesarabais.com/i/photos/custom/900/500/5/159431.jpg);">
            </div>
            <div class="text">Boston</div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/voyage/ameriques/etats-unis/chicago/">
            <div class="imgLittle" style="background-image:url(http://www.unbattementdaile.net/wp-content/uploads/2010/04/21-04-2010-23-12-35.png);">
            </div>
            <div class="text">Chicago</div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/voyage/ameriques/etats-unis/las-vegas/">
            <div class="imgLittle" style="background-image:url(http://www.voyage-unique.com/fr/uploads/etats-unis-las-vegas-la-nuit.jpg);">
            </div>
            <div class="text">Las vegas</div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/voyage/ameriques/etats-unis/los-angeles/">
            <div class="imgLittle" style="background-image:url(http://photos.nouvelles-frontieres.fr/Produits/USACT029_Los-Angeles.jpg);">
            </div>
            <div class="text">Los angeles</div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/voyage/ameriques/etats-unis/miami/">
            <div class="imgLittle" style="background-image:url(http://static.mensup.fr/photos/23094/resorts-world-miami.jpg);">
            </div>
            <div class="text">Miami</div>
         </a>
      </li>
   </span>
   <span>
      <li>
         <a href="/voyage/ameriques/etats-unis/new-york/">
            <div class="imgLittle" style="background-image:url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/06/New_York_in_United_States.svg/langfr-280px-New_York_in_United_States.svg.png);">
            </div>
            <div class="text">New york</div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/voyage/ameriques/etats-unis/nouvelle-orleans/">
            <div class="imgLittle" style="background-image:url(http://idata.over-blog.com/1/24/29/79/Nouvelle-Orl-ans-article1/usa-states-and-capital-map.gif);">
            </div>
             <div class="text">Nouvelle orleans</div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/voyage/ameriques/etats-unis/orlando/">
            <div class="imgLittle" style="background-image:url(http://w0.fast-meteo.com/locationmaps/Orlando.8.gif);">
            </div>
            <div class="text">Orlando</div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/voyage/ameriques/etats-unis/phoenix/">
            <div class="imgLittle" style="background-image:url(http://s.tf1.fr/mmdia/i/38/1/carte-des-etats-unis-avec-phoenix-10852381jjngi_1713.jpg?v=1);">
            </div>
            <div class="text">Phoenix</div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/voyage/ameriques/etats-unis/salt-lake-city-/">
            <div class="imgLittle" style="background-image:url(https://images.rapgenius.com/0210fe9d8964c340748ffb8da065f576.511x367x1.jpg);">
            </div>
            <div class="text">Salt lake city </div>
         </a>
      </li>
   </span>
   <span>
      <li>
         <a href="/voyage/ameriques/etats-unis/san-francisco/">
            <div class="imgLittle" style="backgroundimage:url(http://www.quandpartir.com/meteo/images/villes/etats-unis-san-fransisco-300.jpg);">
            </div>
            <div class="text">San francisco</div>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="/voyage/ameriques/etats-unis/seattle/">
            <div class="imgLittle" style="background-image:url(http://aire-ouest-americaine.e-monsite.com/medias/images/carte-etats-unis-seattle.jpg);">
            </div>
            <div class="text">Seattle</div>
         </a>
      </li>
   </span>
</div>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
.append {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing:10px;
}

/* One closing and opening span every 5 elements for creating row */
.append span { 
    display: table-row;
}

.append li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align:center;
}

/* Display images */
.imgLittle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 85px;
    margin: auto;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.text{
    width: 100%; 
    display: -moz-inline-box;
    text-align: center;    
}
```